# Uninstall Mercurial on a Mac

Tags: mercurial

I installed Mercurial, only to realize that it's not supported yet with MonoDevelop, and then realized that I have no clue how to properly uninstall it.

I've googled around and can't find anything to support uninstalling it.

Comment: How did you install Mercurial? That's the key to "uninstalling" it as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MonoDevelop's support for version control is lagging, and only basic support for Git will be added in version 2.6.  I would suggest keeping Hg installed and use the command line.  You shouldn't dismiss using a great DVCS just because your IDE doesn't integrate with it.

Since Hg is Python based, you may be able to use easy_install to uninstall it for you.

```
easy_install -m mercurial
```

See [easy_install](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html) documentation for more information

Comment: Actually this didn't seem to work, though the command seemed to be successful mercurial was still there. However, I thought about your comments and decided to keep it. I already had downloaded MacHg and so far, so good.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 5):

You can uninstall mercurial by deleting the executable, but this seems to be the only way to fix the problem. The executable is in /usr/local/bin or in usr/local/bin/hg (I'm not quite sure), but deleting the executable (and all related files) is a dirty, but working, way to uninstall mercurial.

Comment: I finally did it similarly to the way you described. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

I did:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/hg # To remove my local version (yours may be elsewhere)
sudo pip uninstall mercurial # To remove mercurial from my Python
```

Pip is not install by default so I guess you can use:

```
easy_install -m mercurial # Like Steve suggests
```

This recipe works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had luck following the suggestion of this post on the [mercurial listserv](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2011-December/041314.html):

> Launch again the mpkg you used for the installation, go to the second
>   window (Read me or something similar) and check the "After the
>   install" section.
>
> On Mac OS X 10.6, the text is: This package installs the hg executable
>   in /usr/local/bin and the Mercurial files in
>   /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial.
>
> I can imagine you have to replace 2.6 by 2.7 on Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 0):

Though totally forgotten how I installed it, the following did the work for me.

```
sudo rm -fr /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial*
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and type this command.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean false;killall Finder
```

Answer (score -4):

Why not simply use the prompt or a 3rd party gui for mercurial? This is usually preferred over IDE Integration for speed/reliability anyways.

Comment: This answer is totally out of topic.