# Can't uninstall Mercurial on Mac

Tags: macos, mercurial

Because of the problem in this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979184/mercurial-on-phabricator-remote-abort-stream-ended-unexpectedly), I'm trying to re-install Mercurial. I find the uninstall instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121432/uninstall-mercurial-on-a-mac). However, when I run `easy_install -m mercurial`, I do not know how to proceed. I'm new to Mac. Could you please tell me what I should do next?

```
sudo easy_install -m mercurial
Password:
Searching for mercurial
Best match: mercurial 3.5.2-20151001

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Because this distribution was installed --multi-version, before you can
import modules from this package in an application, you will need to
'import pkg_resources' and then use a 'require()' call similar to one of
these examples, in order to select the desired version:

    pkg_resources.require("mercurial")  # latest installed version
    pkg_resources.require("mercurial==3.5.2-20151001")  # this exact version
    pkg_resources.require("mercurial>=3.5.2-20151001")  # this version or higher

Processing dependencies for mercurial
Finished processing dependencies for mercurial
```

Comment: You should probably ask this on our sister site [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the answer to the uninstall question is wrong. Not only does `easy_install -m mercurial` not uninstall Mercurial, `easy_install` does not even have an uninstall command to begin with.

To have an uninstall option requires the `pip` command. I don't believe that `pip` is part of the default Mac Python setup, but you can install it using `sudo easy_install pip` and then use `sudo pip uninstall mercurial` (both `pip` and `easy_install` use the same package information, so `pip` can uninstall packages installed with `easy_install`).

Note that `easy_install` may install the `pip` binary in `/usr/local/bin`, which *can* conflict with an existing Python installation through Homebrew (if you're using Homebrew, that is).

There is more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x) about installing `pip` on OS X. The `pip` commands are documented [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/).